# How to fix drupal ajax error

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, drupal-views

Hi have create (content type -> Term reference(field))Tag field for drupal web form using Article page.
 but i have insert any value ajax error has been show up.

```
An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally.
Debugging information follows.
Path: /file/ajax/field_image/und/0/form-CFfxKDg_mCF4RZ5_tr1-10Nxt--BpZKS6A9w_Jn-Ido
StatusText: n/a
ResponseText:
```

how to fix this issue.thanks for feature help.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you change your `$base_url` in settings.php, and your .htaccess has a different url.

For example, if your $base_url is "domain.com" and your .htaccess redirects to "www.domain.com", you may run AJAX errors.